# How I can prevent installation of my android app in phones?

Tags: android, tablet

I am developing a tablet app. How i can prevent installation of apk in phones. I added following lines in manifest.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But it can install on phones too. Is it will be ok, when the app is live?

Comment: How did check?? If you do adb install then it can be installed. These above filters works on Google Play to filter devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find this link awesome: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html

The problem with what we call "tablet" is that the definition is not the same for evryone. I think about the Archos 5IT that is the same size than a phone but branded with "tablet" name. Same issue with Dell Streak.

I would personnaly not call that a tablet..

So if you want to restrict to 7 or 5 inches devices, you should use xlargeScreens and largeScreens.

(There is also a bug in HTC flyer - 7 inches- that uses largeScreens, blame HTC)

I guess that playing with Screen size in Manifest will fit your needs:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

[image]